# Can Windows automatically reboot when new hardware

Tags: windows, esxi, esxi5.5

I have some Windows 7 and Windows 2008 Server R2 VMs running on ESXi 5.5. Some of our servers have slightly different hardware configurations (Some have Xeon E5-2660 CPUs and some have Xeon X5670 CPUs) so sometimes when VMs are provisioned they come up with new hardware detected and need to reboot. Is there a way to detect that there's been new hardware detected and then automatically trigger a reboot only in this case? As the hardware does not otherwise change, it should only trigger once, thus, hopefully, avoiding any reboot loop.

Comment: While I think its possible, Its probably not a good idea.  If there was some issue with a driver, or something else, whatever you setup might result in a constant reboot loop.  Setting a machine, especially a server to reboot automatically is a bad idea

Comment: Right, a reboot loop is what I want to avoid and I've edited the question to hopefully clarify that. We've only got these two configurations. Currently I'm thinking what I might need to do is save either in the registry or in a file what the last known hardware config was and compare it to the current one. If they match, good. If not, update the last known, save, then auto-reboot. Auto-rebooting is not something I would advise in most cases, but in our use case it actually works, as long as we can avoid loops.